# Protractor: Automating E2E Testing -- Select Certificate

Tags: ssl, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm writing E2E - Test for our Business Application's. Because it's an enterprise environment, I have to choose Client Certificates to access the different Webapps (I have installed different certificates for different test users).

As long as I start the tests manually, it's no problem to first select the appropriate cert. But when to trigger them in the automated build, that does not work. I wasn't able to select the certificate using Protractor itself.

At the moment, I've a script which first deletes all cert's, then install's a specific one and start's the test's using IE. With Chrome there is still a pop-up for selecting the cert. So I can run the test's in automation only in IE at the moment.

Has anybody a suggestion, how this could be improved? I tried a lot of things, as suggested by Google, Stackoverflow etc. but nothing really worked. Or has anybody some experience in automating Protractor Test's using different certificates?

Thank's for the help.

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: Hello. Yes we have found a solution. First I need to mention, that in the last 3 years we have improved the E2E testing a lot. We run all these tests now headless in docker continers (except IE of course)
The trick: we run the test without TLS. All requests go to localhost. We wrote a little proxy in typescript which is started with the tests and the desired certificate (as a parameter). The proxy re-routes the requests to the RWC under test. So you can run different tests with different users and different certificates. All done with npm scripts.